# How to fetch all from table1 and attach count of rows from table2 in a single query by laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.8, and I have 2 tables in a (one-to-many) relationship as below:

### Contacts DB

- id
- name
- number

### Send DB

- id
- user_id
- text
- to
- time

what I want to achieve is a list of all (Contacts) along with how many (send) they've made that related to that (contact) by matching Contacts.id with Send.user_id,

here is the result of the query that I'm looking for:

### Query result:

- id
- name
- number
- count of Sends

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your model relationship

Add the following to your `Contact` Model:

```
public function sends()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Send', 'user_id'); //Assuming Send Model is directly in app folder
}
```

Then simply get your information:

```
$contact = Contact::withCount('sends')->get();
```

Comment: Contact::where('id', $id)->withCount('sends')->first(); should do that for you

Comment: how to make the count along with (where)? just count items that matches X

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: how can I achive this : Contact::withCount('sends')->where('to', $to)->get();? don't count all (send) , just (send)s that has to = $to

Comment: Ok, this should do that for you: Contact::whereHas('sends', function($query) use ($to) { return $query->where('to', $to); })->get();

Answer (score 0):

Worked like charm!
I did tweak it to make it return a signal (contact)

```
Contact::where('id', $id)->withCount('sends')->get();
```

here is another way as ([Jonathan K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7996703/jonathan-k)) suggested

```
Contact::where('id', $id)->withCount('sends')->first();
```

Thanks, [Jonathan K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7996703/jonathan-k)